# Orphaned block probability ratio

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

The probability of orphaned blocks should also take into consideration the proportion of the total mining hash power that the miner has.
If M_i and M_j are 2 miners with p_i= 2* p_j (proportion of their relative mining hash power) then in that case what is the ratio of the probability of orphaned blocks o_i and o_j

Under the assumption that mining delays exist and all miners are honest.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: lol yup. does that make this unanswerable?

Comment: No, but it means you should probably find the answer yourself. If you have specific questions about something you don't understand while trying to answer that, by all means, ask it here. But this isn't the place to give you an answer you can copy-paste.

Comment: yup. makes sense. this entire question was tough to comprehend. but anyway thanks for your help.